# Satyr Bard Spells and College Choices

Tags: dnd-5e, bard, character-levels

I'm a new Level 3 Satyr Bard! Any suggestions on college preferences (and why), along with spells that I might want to use for unexpected damage! Background, my Satyr is a freeloving girl who talks your ear off, never knows a stranger (and wants to befriend everyone). She also happens to bake casseroles and steal locks of hair. Her choice of instrument is a cow bell.

Comment: Hey Bobbi Jo, it’s great that you are getting into the game! We don’t handle questions that are primarily opinion based here on the main site, but if you join us in [chat], I’m sure there are others who would love to give some recommendations.

Comment: While we don't accept opinion-based questions, we can handle [tag:optimization] question if you can give us a clear goal and appropriate restrictions for what you are after. E.g. What sources/materials are allowed? What is the character goal you are trying to achieve; highest damage (per round or bust damage), best utility, best healing? Without knowing what you want to achieve with this character we can't give advice on what will be the best choices to achieve it. You can add this information via an [edit] and it may get the question reopened. Good luck!